# MS Access - A relationships already exists

Tags: ms-access, office365

I am using MS Office 365 Access application and facing relationships already exists error When creating a Foreign Key constraint between two tables.

Table 1: sc_user where student_id is primary key
Table 2: sc_user_course where same student_id to be the foreign key

In the table 2 already one more FK is there (course_id) between sc_course and sc_user_course table.

[Schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stTb7.png)

I tried adding two ids as a foreign key but getting error. Also I tried using Lookup method even getting same error.

Comment: It seems like you must rethink your schema. Creating two opposite one-to-many relations between two tables make no sense to me.

Comment: Save as Gustav, but in my words start over and review table normalization again.  In particular relationships are formed by primary keys and foreign keys(don't connect course-fee to course-fee).  and many to many relationships which are formed by a junction table like sc-user_course has foreign keys for sc-user and course but course and sc-user do not have foreign-keys for the junction tables.